# qstring white space

Tags: qt

```
  QString fe = "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2008\\bin\\imconvert.exe ";
```

This line gives a problem because of space between Program and Files. How is it possible to decode it so that it is treated as one complete string

Brgds,

kNish

Comment: Manually eliminate the space by traversing the string

Comment: QString fe = "C:\\Program%20Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2008\\bin\\imconvert.exe "; works

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.trolltech.org/4.7/qfileinfo.html#details) object to store it. This object accepts all path even if they have spaces. In addition you have some functions to do all checks you need before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QUrl::toPercentEncoding` static method

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Why should be it a comment? There is not much to write about it and it answers question.

Answer (score 0):

In windows you would do:

```
QString fe = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2008\\bin\\imconvert.exe\"";
```